# Recovery Partition Healthy?

Tags: windows-7, recovery-partition

I tried to backup my recovery partition a couple of times on a CD and HDD but this process fails every time. I used "Dell Datasafe Local Backup-Basic Edition", but after 2 minutes of burning/writing the recovery image it fails and says to try again.

I now want to use my recovery partition again to restore my Laptop to its default factory settings, but since the backup process has failed, I am not sure if the recovery partition is healthy.

How can I check how healthy the partition is (or if the data is intact).

Comment: What do you mean check if the partition is healthy.  It sounds like the recovery image is corrupt.  You will have to talk to Dell about alternatives.